# How to conditionally fill new column using for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I want to add a new column and fill values based on condition.

```
df:
indicator, value, a, b
1, 20, 5, 3
0, 30, 6, 8
0, 70, 2, 2
1, 10, 3, 7
```

I want to add a new column (`value_new`) based on Indicator. If `indicator == 1`, `value_new = a*b` otherwise `value_new = value`.

```
df:
indicator, value, a, b, value_new
1, 20, 5, 3, 15
0, 30, 6, 8, 30
0, 70, 2, 2, 70
1, 10, 3, 7, 21
```

I have tried following:

```
value_new = []
for in in range(1, len(df)):
  if indicator[i] == 1:
    value_new.append(df['a'][i]*df['b'][i])
  else:
    value_new.append(df['value'][i])
df['value_new'] = value_new
```

`Error: 'Length of values does not match length of index'`

And I have also tried:

```
for in in range(1, len(df)):
  if indicator[i] == 1:
    df['value_new'][i] = df['a'][i]*df['b'][i]
  else:
    df['value_new'][i] = df['value'][i]
```

`KeyError: 'value_new'`

Comment: rows = len(df) for i in range(rows):  <- give this a try. It will define the len as a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['value_new'] = np.where(df['indicator'], df['a']*df['b'], df['value'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   indicator  value  a  b  value_new
0          1     20  5  3         15
1          0     30  6  8         30
2          0     70  2  2         70
3          1     10  3  7         21
```

Comment: Would you be able to keep the preceding code using this?

Comment: Wouldn't this make the multiplication if `indicator` is any positive integer except 1 too? It's better to write the full condition `df['indicator'] == 1`.